# How to fix the IDs renaming problem while using View Binding in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity, android-viewbinding

The problem is that when I rename the id of any view like a button in the xml file, the name of the view doesn't get updated in the activity while using view binding.

When I rename the id, I use (refactor) or (shift+f6).

This is a big problem because when ever I rename an id in the XML file, it will break the code in the activity in case I'm using View Binding.

Example:-

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

when I change Button1 to Button2, the code breaks in the activity in case I'm using View binding.

Can anyone give me any way to properly rename the IDs so that the names in the activity get updated automatically while using View Binding.

Please, remember I do use (refactor) not f2.

If you agree with me that this is a very urging problem and it breaks our code, please vote this question up, so it will be suggested to more android developers. Maybe some already found a solution.

Comment: Afaik: This is not possible, at least not yet

Comment: @JustSightseeing , All this time since they introduce view binding and they didn't fix this code breaker problem?. This makes me have a lot of doubts in skills of the android team at google. Unless they did it on purpose.

Comment: To be honest I feel like that was on purpose, I myself have multiple views that contain the same ID, in different fragments, sometimes across different modules, if every time I renamed a view in a fragment I had to check other fragments (and the fragment classes) because it could rename also the views there (on accident), that would be way worse, so I think that's a feature, not a bug ;)